# Routing table configuration

Tags: networking, routing, configuration

Suppose having an routing table in which the default-route is missing
can a router work without a default-route or the table is incomplete?

and having these two entries is also legit or there is an overlap problem for the network addresses?

```
Type        Network            Next Hop
s           130.192.16.0/22    130.192.11.254
s           130.192.16.8/28    130.192.11.254
```

Comment: Did you mean /29 in the second line?

Comment: No it's 28 and I'm asking because if it's YES on my both questions then there the second address is not an valid network address.

Comment: 130.192.16.8/28 it's not a valid route. `130.192.16.8/29` or `130.192.16.0/28` are. - http://pastebin.com/UKDr37fd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question, the answer is 'yes'. The router will work, but only the networks in the routing table will be accessible. For everything else, you'll get a "destination host unreachable".

For the second, if you have two (or more) overlaping networks, the [longest-prefix-match](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_prefix_match) will be used.
So, if you want to access `130.192.16.9`, the second route will be used (doesn't matter in your case, since both use the same gateway), because the the match is longer (more bits match the network ID/mask).

If you have:

```
10.0.0.0/8 via gw1
10.0.0.0/16 via gw2
10.0.0.0/24 via gw3
10.0.0.0/30 via gw4
```

and want to ping `10.0.0.1`, the packet will go via `gw4`, since it matches more bits with the network id/mask then other routes.

Edit:

```
130.192.16.8/28
```

is not a valid route (if you use /28, `130.192.16.0` is a network ID). However  `130.192.16.8/29` is a valid route.

Comment: thanks, still is it possible for the second address to get an error because that is not an valid network address ?